# Friefox/Chrome Add-on: How to detect that the body has changed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I need to create some sort of listener and fire whenever the page is being injected with external code (ember) when a new `<div>` with a specific class is added, I need to perform plug-in logic. Is it actually possible to do that from within a Add-on in Firefox/Chrome?

Comment: You could use the mutation observer (https://javascript.info/mutation-observer) in your content script (which is injected in the page).

Comment: @ArslanAli Thanks this helped. I'm now stuck on cycling the nodes, I don't know but I cannot filter the relevant tag, here is my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71473992/how-to-target-specific-tag-in-mutation-observer

Comment: Glad it helped! I will try to look into your other question