# How to target specific tag in Mutation Observer

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I'm trying something like this:

`var pin = document.querySelector("#notice ul li div p a");`

The idea is to narrow down the observer and filter only the relevant element(s) in this case all 'a' inside the nested tags. The ID 'notice' is the only tag with an ID, I then need to select the first 'ul' then 'li' and so on, until I reach the 'a' I'm interested in.

Passing this to the observer, which is listening with the following options:

`const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };`

So I have the `observer.observe(pin, config);` and relative `let observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {` However I must be doing something wrong sing it is not pulling anything. It only works if I use this:

`var pin = document.querySelector("#notice");`

How can I limit the observer to only relevant portion I'm interested in? I know I could monitor the whole document body, but will affect CPU load and do unnecessary operations since what I need to isolate in just a specific tag.

**this is the sample HTML I'm workin on**

```
<section id="notice">
<ul>
   <li>      
      <div>  
          <p>
            <a href="locale.html?58651456454">Translate</a>
      </p>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you show us what the HTML looks like? Without any further details, all we can tell you is that something is wrong with the selector (and this problem is unrelated to mutation observers).

Comment: @SuperStormer edited with HTML nested `a` I'm looking to target, all this `section` is added by an `ember.js` script so the `?` parameter is unknown until I lookup after the Mutation.

Comment: still need help? i think the first param isnt a live selector

Comment: @aehlke I resolved, I don't remember precisely on what step I were but the add-on has been published by now so I must have resolved somehow.